# Calling other method of class, not only simple parent/children relation

Tags: flutter, dart

When I call the children class from parent class I can use `GlobalObjectKey`

and when I call the parent method from chidlren class I can use `callback`

This two can work when structure is simple.

However when there are more complex structure.

such as

- calling method from parents of parents of brother.
- calling method from children of children of brother.
- calling method which dosen't have relevant.

Is there any good method for this purpose??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is a good method but you can create a dart file with method written globally (not inside a class). These methods can be accessed by any class by just importing the dart file and variables inside this dart file persists throught the session too.

Comment: I see. separating file sounds good for this purpose.